# Is there any way to verify VS was installed successfully?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I was downloading Visual Studio 2017 and I went to work, when I came back my computer was shut down, and I don't know is the download was finished before it happened.

Is there any way to confirm that?

Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Just run the installer again. If it's correctly installed it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerun the installer, if the installation was successful, it should look like this or with update instead of modify. Secondarily click on **more** and let the installer repair your installation.

[image]